# php string function to get substring before the last occurrence of a character

Tags: php

```
$string = "Hello World Again".
echo strrchr($string , ' '); // Gets ' Again'
```

Now I want to get "Hello World" from the `$string` [The substring before the last occurrence of a space ' ' ]. How do I get it??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is kind of a cheap way to do it, but you could split, pop, and then  join to get it done:

```
$string = 'Hello World Again';
$string = explode(' ', $string);
array_pop($string);
$string = implode(' ', $string);
```

Comment: this is a horrible way to do this especially since there is a command getting the last occurrence of a certain character (strrpos)

Answer (score 64):

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
echo substr($string, 0, strrpos( $string, ' ') ); //Hello World
```

If the character isn't found, nothing is echoed

Answer (score 7):

One (nice and chilled out) way:

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
$t1=explode(' ',$string);
array_pop($t1);
$t2=implode(' ',$t1);
print_r($t2);
```

Other (more tricky) ways:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\s+\S+$~', '', $string);
```

or

```
$result = implode(" ", array_slice(str_word_count($string, 1), 0, -1));
```

Comment: @sdleihssirhc thanks for writing that comment because otherwise people would now not know who was the fastest kid here. thats right, vote for me people.

Comment: @locrizak dude, 3 operations not 4.

Comment: @locrizak check the 1 operation kung fu and weep.

Comment: Just because something is written in one line does not make it one operation. The preg_replace is one operation but is specific to whitespace (the question asked about any character).

Comment: @zaf Still 3 for one that looks like it will work... meouw answer is definetly the way to go to me. Neat and clean

Comment: @andrewtweber no, the question is quite explicit about the whitespace. go on, no harm in reading the question again.

Comment: @Yehonatan Read the damn question title. "last occurrence of **a character**"

Comment: The best solution with `preg_replace` I think. [`sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54c1727d7209583f32770039bf34e4106ecfe462)

Answer (score 6):

[strripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) — Find the position of the last occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string

```
 $string = "hello world again";
 echo substr($string, 0, strripos($string, ' ')); // Hello world
```

Comment: Essentially the same code as in @Till answer, and without any explanation too.

Answer (score 5):

```
$myString = "Hello World Again";
echo substr($myString, 0, strrpos($myString, " "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), which gets the position of the last instance of a given string within a string, and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to return the value.

Answer (score 1):

The correct implementation should be:

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
$pos = strrpos( $string, ' ');
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo substr($string, 0, $pos ); //Hello World
}
```

Otherwise if the character is not found it will print nothing. See following case:

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
//prints nothing as : is not found and strrpos returns false.
echo substr($string, 0, strrpos( $string, ':') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
echo preg_replace('# [^ ]*$', '', $string);
```

This will work regardless of whether the character occurs in the string or not. It will also work if the last character is a space.

Comment: Dont forget the # as a delimiter!

Comment: This would actually be the approach I would use ...if the code was valid. :(

Answer (score 0):

The most direct, single-function approach is to use `preg_replace()` to remove the last space and all remaining characters (which logically cannot include any spaces).

This is suitable for a wide range of textual scenarios and is easy to adjust because there are just 3 basic components in the pattern.

- match a space
`[^ ]*` - match zero or more non-space characters
`$` - match the end of the string

If there are no spaces in the input string, then the input string will remain unchanged.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S2853))

```
$string = "Hello World Again";
var_export(preg_replace('/ [^ ]*$/', '', $string));
// 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function cutTo($string, $symbol) {
    return substr($string, 0, strpos($string, $symbol));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
   $str = "Hello World!";
   echo $str . "<br>";
   echo chop($str,"World!");
   // output - Hello 

?>
```