# php cut string by character

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php string function to get substring before the last occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939412/php-string-function-to-get-substring-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character)

i have string

```
'storage/product/home_decor/living_room/livingroom/7ce3da03b6854283bdd0b8e33b3e556a.11.09.2012.03.42.33.jpg'
```

how do I cut the last string by / with php ?

i want my output is

```
'storage/product/home_decor/living_room/livingroom/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep that last / with your result, use this code:

```
$string = 'storage/product/home_decor/living_room/livingroom/7ce3da03b6854283bdd0b8e33b3e556a.11.09.2012.03.42.33.jpg';
$min = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '/') + 1);
echo $min; //output : storage/product/home_decor/living_room/livingroom/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '/'));
```

Comment: What about using [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)?