# Trim string at last occurrence of a hyphen

Tags: php, string

I would like to remove the last number including the dash from this string:

```
hello-world-093
```

the result should be:

```
hello-world
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php string function to get substring before the last occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939412/php-string-function-to-get-substring-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

`mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] );`

in your case it should be something like :

```
$subject = 'hello-world-093' ;
$subject_stripped = preg_replace ( '/-[0-9]*$/' , '' , $subject);
```

The above pattern will delete the `-` and all numbers that follow at the end of the string.

Comment: What about including period.
I want this input CHE979175BLK40.5
to return this CHE979175BLK

Comment: @Jafer.balti in your case try either of these:
`echo preg_replace ( '/[0-9]*\.+[0-9]*$/' , '' , $str);`
`echo preg_replace ( '/[0-9\.]*$/' , '' , $str);`

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

*strrpos — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string*

Do `strrpos` with the character `-` and you know that the result will be the last position of a `-` in the string.

Now, you can get only the first portion of the string by using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and supplying your position as the length.

Comment: The problem here is that it won't always be hello-world-093 it may be different like test-03 or hello-testing-here-98.

Comment: @Jose Cardama That is not a problem. Notice I am using `strrpos` not `strpos`, and strrpos finds the LAST occurence of `-` not the first `-` so it doesn't matter how many there are so long as it's everything after the last one you want to remove.

Comment: any example please? iam kind of new to this and iam lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. I offer this not as the best way way but just another way to skin a cat. I think it's important to understand there are many ways to solve a problem and to explore them. You'll learn a lot by learning to tackle a problem from different angles.

```
<?php 
$pattern = "/^(.*)-[0-9]*$/";
$string = "hello-world-093";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```