# Remove all characters after last / in URL

Tags: php

i need to remove all characters **after** the last slash of Url

My URL:

```
http://www.example.com/page_with_loop/articel
```

And i need php code that outputs:

```
http://www.example.com/page_with_loop/
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.... and while solution is extremely simple (practically a one liner), nobody should be giving it to you.

Comment: Use `substr` and `strrpos`.

Comment: also, there are over 50 questions on SO that have a solution for your exact problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939412/php-string-function-to-get-substring-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character

Comment: You could do a redirect for all `category/.+` to `category/` in your `.htaccess` (depending on server version).

Comment: thanks chris! I dont use categorys on my site. the permastructure is domain.com/page_with_loop/article

Comment: It's the same logic. Just swap `category` with your term(s).

Comment: its for displaying my breacrumbs, that wont work. I need some code that displays the permalink of article without the part after last slash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php string function to get substring before the last occurrence of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939412/php-string-function-to-get-substring-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$urlInput = "http://example.com/category/article";
$urlDeletePos = strlen($urlInput) - strlen(strrchr($urlInput));
$urlOutput = substr($urlInput,0,$urlDeletePos);
echo "Shortened URL is $urlOutput";
```

Comment: Thank u very much dude! 

Is it possible to put it in together like this:

    <a href="<?php ... ?>" title=""> </a>

Comment: You can thank me by selecting my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: Just insert the code in the PHP section? The echo command will output the link.

Comment: I will, but i doesnt work. Sorry, im no php coder, otherwise i wouldnt disturb people here, but looks like ur friendly! ;)

Comment: I am friendly I think ;) but I must agree with the others... This is no programming factory here and putting in my code in your section and debugging the error is some basic php knowledge you can learn in a few minutes by googling it.

Comment: Could you just mark my answer as the correct one? Because it is and it's not my fault you aren't able to integrate it correctly... Any updates on the issue?